# GraphQL efficiently do the same query on an array of variables

Tags: graphql

I want to run a very similar GraphQL query over a given input set. I figure I could write a loop in my client, but I was wondering if there was a way to use GraphQL to just iterate over my list by feeding it an array as a variable.

e.g., given this query against Github V4 API

```
query {
  nasa: organization(login: "nasa") {
     ...orgFields
  }
  github: organization(login: "github") {
    ...orgFields
  }
}

fragment orgFields on Organization {
  name
  url
  id
}
```

Is there some way I could pass an array like `orgs = ["nasa","github"]` and it will have the same effect as if I wrote out multiple aliased queries? Or is the only option to programatically create the query and concatenate strings for each alias. E.g., the same idea as if I did something like `login: "nasa" OR "github"`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the GitHub API documentation, you cannot pass an array of `organizations` as you are explaining.

Unless GitHub updates their API to support it, for now you would have to go for your second option:

> Or is the only option to programmatically create the query and concatenate strings for each alias. E.g., the same idea as if I did something like login: "nasa" OR "github".

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean it depends on server implementation, i.e., there is nothing in the graphql lang that can formulate the query or convert it?

Comment: Yes, it’s a server implementation.